# Javascript replace dots with regular expression, but not works

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm sorry, but I can't find working dot replacement on stackoverflow.
Peoples ask about replacing

```
var str = '. 950.000.000, -';
str = str.replace(/\./gi, '');
alert(parseInt(str)); // yes, it works & will output correctly
```

But, it wouldn't works, when my 'str' var is : Rp. 950.000,- . It is currency format in my area, and i want to do math with it. I do this, and not work:

```
var str = 'Rp. 950.000, -';
str = str.replace(/\./gi, '');// i dont know, but the str values now is nothing
alert(parseInt(str)); // sure, it outputs nothing
```

I just want to replace all dots (so it will not bothers math operation, because dot is a decimal on number).

Comment: output of str.replace is `"Rp 950000, -"`

Comment: You're trying to use `parseInt` on something that is not a number. Your `alert` will print `NaN`. Just remove the `parseInt` if all you want is: `Rp 950000, -`

Comment: This approach sounds culturally-broken (or culture-centric, depending on how it's viewed). How should `1.234,56` (or `1,234.56`) be treated?

Comment: Thank you  Guys! all i want is 950000 so i can math it. Answers below answered the question :D thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing all the dots in the string `'Rp. 950.000, -'` you will be left with `'Rp 950000, -'`.  If you try to use this string for `parseInt()` it will fail because of the letters at the beginning and the other characters at the end.  If you want to remove all non-digit characters from you string you can use the following:

```
str = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

After this `parseInt()` should work fine and give you `950000`.

Comment: Thank you for answers. the answer of others also good. Thank you all. I choose this because this explain why my source not works. Thanks

Comment: `parseInt` would not fail because of non-digit characters at the end - it ignores any trailing non-digits. Leading non-digits are a different story

Answer (score 2):

Why not replace everything that is not a number with `\D`?

```
var str = 'Rp. 950.000, -';
str = str.replace(/\D/gi, '');// i dont know, but the str values now is nothing
alert(parseInt(str, 10));
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/e8dMD/1/

Comment: Unless you have decimal places like 950.000,25. But that's not what Jahe asked...